# Allocating and freeing memory

Tags: c

My question is quite simple. We generally allocate memory by declaring a pointer and then assigning a block of memory to that pointer. Suppose somewhere in the code I happen to use

`ptr = ptr + 1`

and then I use

`free(ptr)`

can someone tell what will happen. The entire memory block will get deallocated or something else. Can I partially deallocate the memory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must always pass *exactly* the same pointer to `free` that you got from `malloc` (or `realloc`.)  If you don't, the "behavior is undefined", which is a term of art that means you can't rely on the program behaving in any predictable way.  In this case, though, you should expect it to crash immediately.  (If you get unlucky, it will instead corrupt memory, causing a crash some time later, or worse, incorrect output.)

The only way to partially deallocate memory is `realloc` with a smaller size, but that's only good for trimming at the end and isn't guaranteed to make the trimmed-off chunk available for some other allocation.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to deallocate part of a memory block. The only thing you can do is reallocate the block giving it a different size. However this does not guarantee that the block will land in the same place in memory (it might be copied somewhere else).

Answer (score 1):

You must pass to free() the same pointer to the same location malloc() returned. That's because the allocator keeps a sort of list of the blocks you allocated (@everyone: feel free to add/modify if I'm wrong) and if the pointer you pass to free doesn't compare it this list free() complains ("bad memory block" maybe?). To partly deallocate the memory you should use realloc(), which changes the dimensions of that block of memory, but is slow and inefficient. You should use it only when you're sure of the new size of the block or leaving more space to fill in the future.

Comment: So you mean that the allocator keeps a list and frees the whole block iff we free a pointer containing the address of first byte of that block?

Comment: @bubble How does this get 2 upvotes? Since when do you pass pointers to malloc?

Comment: @bubble: yes, it remembers how many bytes you allocated for each block

Comment: @BlackBear The first sentence is OK now, but the rest is nonsense. That's all implementation detail and varies from compiler to compiler. It's undefined behaviour and there's no need to say any more than that.

Comment: @David I voted it up so that we can have more discussion on it. BlackBear very assertively wrote something which I wanted to confirm.

Comment: @bubble you don't need to upvote to discuss. Anyway, you know now that this code is an error!

Answer (score 1):

malloc() , free() and realloc() are not part of C language.

These are functions defines in standard library. Code in standard library that deals with it  is usually called "allocator". So, actual answer is "It depends on C library".

On Linux, glibc would crash the program.
On VC++, C runtime would corrupt allocator's state

Source code is available for these libraries, so you can actually put a breakpoint and step into free.

Comment: Calling the standard C library "not part of [the] C language" is not  *wrong* but strikes me as unduly fine hair-splitting.

Comment: Reason for not calling it part of C language is because you can customize behavior either by sing a different library (with same compiler) or writing your own code for malloc / free. I used to do that around 98 - 99. This gives you benefits like writing a version that would print out list of all allocated blocks in debugger.